# How to Iterate through data present in the spread sheet in selenium/data

Tags: python, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am automating a web page where the data is entered in web pages from spread sheet like name ,date of birth.i am able to run if there a single record in a spread sheet.the issue is i don't how to iterate through the spread sheet if i have n number data in a spread sheet .

Below,as of now,i able to fetch the 1 record.i would like to fetch both record 1&2

```
Example as in spread sheet:
 Record  Name   DOB
    1    TEST1  05/06/2010
    2    TEST2  06/05/2010
```

Please find the code i have tried so far

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('path')
driver.fullscreen_window();
driver.get('url');
time.sleep(5);
Workbook=xlrd.open_workbook("excelpath")
Customerdetails = Workbook.sheet_by_index(0);
Storagezipcode = Customerdetails.cell(1,0);
text_area=driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//*[@id="QuoteDetails/PostalCode"])[2]');
text_area.send_keys(Storagezipcode.value);
Nextbutton=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"Next")]');
Nextbutton.click()
time.sleep(10)
#carlink page
CarLink=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="link"]');
CarLink.click();
time.sleep(30)
#ModelYear page
yeardetail=Customerdetails.cell(1,14);
Yearlink = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[normalize-space(.)='{}']".format(yeardetail.value));
Yearlink.click();
time.sleep(10)
#Company name
SubModel=Customerdetails.cell(1,15);
SubModellink=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[normalize-space(.)='{}']".format(SubModel.value));
SubModellink.click();
time.sleep(10)
#Company model
Bodymodel=Customerdetails.cell(1,16);
Bodylink=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[normalize-space(.)='{}']".format(Bodymodel.value));
Bodylink.click();
time.sleep(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the row count to get all the rows and then iterate and use column index.

```
import xlrd
Workbook=xlrd.open_workbook("excelpath")
Customerdetails = Workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
for i in range(1,Customerdetails.nrows):
    Record=Customerdetails.cell(i,0)
    print(Record.value)
    Name= Customerdetails.cell(i,1)
    print(Name.value)
    DOB = Customerdetails.cell(i, 2)
    print(DOB.value)
```

Comment: i am also getting a value from the webpage and storing it in the excel depending on each record,so can the above method work in that situation also.

Comment: For storing data if you know the number of  rows then it should work fine.Make sure loop always start from 1 because 0 is the header element.

Comment: To store data from web page  to excel pandas library is another good options.